# How to create a Category Article listing with subcategories?

Tags: 7, views

I am new to drupal 7 and I want following page:

```
  Main Category

  (1) Subcategory1
    - post1
      Details
    - post 2
      Details
  (2) Subcategory2
    - post1
      Details
    - post 2
      Details
```

How can I do that? I think I can use Views but I need some further details.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal Taxonomy is used to Categorize Content... Please have a look @ detailed [tutorial here](http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-13-drupal-7-taxonomy-vocabulary-terms-tags-categories-concepts) how to use taxonomy concept in Drupal to create categories and tag contents with categories.

You need to use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to display the content by category.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know i can use view but i require particular structure that it is what i need to achive but I can't get. Tutorial given by will not able to render me structure that I need.

Answer (score 0):

it's a lengthy process actually.

1.create a view with the `'taxonomy vocabulary'` you need to show.

2.next add a relatioship `'Taxonomy term: content using {Vocabulary}'` this will allow you to get the content that is having the vocabulary you need.

3. next you can add a contextual `Taxonomy term: Parent term`     read more [How does Views contextual filters work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78071/how-does-views-contextual-filters-work) ( you can skip this part and see what you get first )
4. Add the 'Fields' you need to show up from the content.
   example you can add the  `'content title. taxonomy term name, taxonomy term id'`
5. The Finaly got to `'FORMAT' | Settings` group it by your `taxonomy term name` in your fields. select 'Use rendered output to group rows'